# What happened to the $\Delta x$?

Tags: integration

> What happened to the $\Delta x$?

In a county the population density per quadratic kilometer is assessed  to vary according to $f=\frac{8000}{x\sqrt{x}}$, where $x$ is the distance to the county's center. How many people live in the annulus from $x=1$ to $x=4$?

**Solution:**

The area of the annulus can be said to equal $2\pi x\Delta x$ (draw a figure), so therefore the amount of people who live in the annulus from $x=1$ to $x=4$ is equal to $\int _1^4dx\frac{8000}{\sqrt{x}x}2\pi x$. But why is the $\Delta x$ not used in the calculation of the integral?

Comment: It is replaced by ${\mathrm d}x$

Comment: The $\Delta x$ "becomes" the $dx$

Comment: Uhm... @mixedmath, may I ask why/how?

Comment: The original idea behind the integral notation is that $\sum\Delta x\to \int dx$ as you make the partition finer and finer. Whether you consider it rigorous with modern eyes is a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We write $\Delta x$ to represent a change in the value of $x$. We often consider splitting up a region into pieces of size $\Delta x$, for example splitting an annulus into smaller annuli each with thickness $\Delta x$.

But multiplying population times area only works if population is constant.  So we want to think of splitting the big annulus into very small annuli, each with infinitesimally small thickness (we are essentially thinking of $\Delta x \to 0$). When we do this we usually replace $\Delta x$ with $dx$. In this way, we replace
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i}) 2 \pi x_{i} \Delta x$$
where $\Delta x = \frac{4-1}{n}$ and $x_{i}$ is some point between $1 + (i-1) \Delta x$ and $1+i \Delta x$ with the limit as $n \to \infty$ (so as $\Delta x \to 0$) which we write as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i}) 2 \pi x_{i} \Delta x = \int_{1}^{4} f(x)2\pi x dx.$$

Comment: The books frequently used in Swedish Gymnasiums do not always give very rigid explanations, just so you know! But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The area of the annulus can be said to equal to $2\pi x\Delta x$ **only if** $\Delta x \to 0$. And this is usually represented by the symbol $dx$ .